# Why my Eclipse not showing TESTNG during execution?

Tags: eclipse, testng

I installed **TestNG** into my eclipse editor from **Eclipse market place**, but it's showing "**JUnit Test**" instead of "**TestNG**" in "**Run as**" options.

Why my Eclipse not showing **TestNG** during execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to file<JAVA Project<create any name for project name<click
   finish.
2. Go to New<Other<search for "TestNG" in wizard input field<click
   "TestNG class"<click "Next".
3. In Source Folder, click browse for src folder created in first step,
   click OK
4. In Package name input field, we can enter any name in the field.
5. In "Class Name" input field, we can enter any name in the field and
   click finish.